# Branch coverage zero percent in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have written some test cases and everything seems fine except the following one. I am getting zero branch cover for one file. I have googled couple of blog and I came to understand if the statement cab be executed in multiple scenario that call branch coverage. But I don't find my code can be executed in multiple way.

request.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default async (request, httpService = axios) => {
  const {
    method, url, data, headers,
  } = request;
  return httpService.request({
    method,
    url,
    headers: Object.assign({}, headers),
    data,
  });
};
```

reqeust.test.js

```
describe('requestServie', () => {
  it('should have a valid request object', async () => {
    const requestObj = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://mock.url',
      data: {},
    };

    const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({}));

    const httpService = {
      request: mockRequest,
    };

    await request(requestObj, httpService);
    expect(mockRequest).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      method: requestObj.method,
      url: requestObj.url,
      headers: {},
      data: requestObj.data,
    });
  });

  it('should return a valid response (empty)', async () => {
    const response = {
      data: {
      },
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: {},
      config: {},
      request: {},
    };

    const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(response));

    const httpService = {
      request: mockRequest,
    };

    const res = await request({ url: 'http://mock.url' }, httpService);

    expect(res).not.toBe(null);
    expect(res).toMatchObject(
      {
        status: response.status,
      },
    );
  });
});
```

**Edit**

rquest.js

```
export default async (request, httpService = axios) => {
  const {
    method, url, data, headers,
  } = request;
  return httpService.request({
    method,
    url,
    headers: Object.assign({}, headers),
    data,
  }).then(successResponse, (error) => {
    throwHttpError(error);
  });
};
```

request.test.js

```
import HttpError from 'standard-http-error';
import axios from 'axios';
import request, { successResponse, throwHttpError } from './requestService';

describe('requestService', () => {

  jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    request: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})),
  }));

  describe('successResponse', () => {
    const mockRes = {
      status: 9001,
      data: {
        stuff: 'stuff',
      },
    };
    it('should returns an object with only status and data properties', () => {
      const responseKeys = Object.keys(successResponse(mockRes));
      expect(responseKeys).toMatchObject(['status', 'data']);
      expect(responseKeys.length).toBe(2);
    });

    it('should map the status of the reponse to the status property', () => {
      expect(successResponse(mockRes).status)
        .toBe(mockRes.status);
    });

    it('should map the data of the reponse to the data property', () => {
      expect(successResponse(mockRes).data)
        .toMatchObject(mockRes.data);
    });

    it('should have a valid request object', async () => {
      const requestObj = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://mock.url',
        data: {},
        headers: {},
      };

      const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({}));

      const httpService = {
        request: mockRequest,
      };

      await request(requestObj, httpService);
      expect(mockRequest).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        method: requestObj.method,
        url: requestObj.url,
        headers: {},
        data: requestObj.data,
      });
    });
  });

  describe('httpThrowError', () => {
    const mockErr = {
      response: {
        status: 9001,
        statusText: 'error message goes here',
      },
    };

    it('should map the status of the reponse to the error.status property', () => {
      try {
        throwHttpError(mockErr);
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e).not.toBe(null);
        expect(e.status).toBe(mockErr.response.status);
        expect(e.message).toBe(mockErr.response.statusText);
      }
    });

    it('should map the data of the reponse to the error.data property', () => {
      const mockErrWithData = Object.assign({}, mockErr);
      mockErrWithData.response.data = {};
      try {
        throwHttpError(mockErrWithData);
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e).not.toBe(null);
        expect(e.data).toBe(mockErrWithData.response.data);
      }
    });
  });

  describe('request', () => {
    const testCases = [
      ['should return error response on server error', 500],
      ['should return error response on bad request', 400],
      ['should return error response on unauthorised', 401],
    ];

    testCases.forEach(([testName, errorStatus]) => {
      it(testName, async () => {
        const errorResponse = {
          response: {
            status: errorStatus,
          },
        };
        const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(errorResponse));

        const httpService = {
          request: mockRequest,
        };

        try {
          await request({ url: 'http://mock.url' }, httpService);
          throw new Error('Expected an exception, but none was thrown');
        } catch (err) {
          expect(err).not.toBe(null);
          expect(err).toMatchObject(
            new HttpError(errorResponse.response.status,
              errorResponse.response.statusText),
          );
        }
      });
    });

    it('should return an valid response (empty)', async () => {
      const response = {
        data: {
          meta: {},
          results: [],
        },
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'OK',
        headers: {},
        config: {},
        request: {},
      };

      const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(response));

      const httpService = {
        request: mockRequest,
      };

      const res = await request({ url: 'http://mock.url' }, httpService);

      expect(res).not.toBe(null);
      expect(res).toMatchObject(
        {
          status: response.status,
          data: response.data,
        },
      );
    });

    it('should use axios by default', async () => {
      const req = { url: 'http://mock.url', method: 'get' };
      await request(req);
      expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

> Error

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Updated 15/Nov/18**

**"jest": "^23.6.0",**

```
import HttpError from 'standard-http-error';
import axios from 'axios';
import request, { successResponse, throwHttpError } from './requestService';

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  request: jest.fn(),
}));
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what is not covered you can go to `coverage/Iconv-report` and open `index.html`. Those are created once you run `jest` with `--coverage` [option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#coverage).

It looks like uncovered branch is: `httpService = axios`. So you need to check if default `axios` is used.

To cover that you may run request without `httpService` argument - you can [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) `axios` globally for that, i.e.:

```
import axios from 'axios';

// note that mock goes before any describe block

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    request: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})),
  }
});

describe('requestService', () => {

  // ... your other tests

  it('should use axios by default', async () => {
    const opts = { url: 'http://mock.url', method: 'get' };
    const res = await request(opts);
    expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Note that `jest.mock` have some [buggy behavior when running inside a spec](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please give some example how to do that as I am quite new to jest

Comment: @Carlos, your tests looks good for the person who just started using jest! I updated the answer with info you might find useful.

Comment: it is throwing some error probably because of I had modified the API request function. I have used jest.fn(() => Promise.reject({})) as well seems not working. I have added my question with updated code

Comment: @Carlos, you seems to have covered 200%! Put `jest.mock(...)` out of `describe`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter you might find helpful

Comment: Initially it was out of describe but had a same issue. I am trying to avoid extra dependency as much as possible

Comment: @Carlos, I've thought it's closed question... Any other thing I can help you with this? For the latest error you faced - try to move `jest.mock(...)` out of any `describe()` i.e. right after `import` statements.

Comment: it seemed like jest.mock is not mocking the axios at all. I have updated my question

Comment: @Carlos, `can't read property .then from undefined` means that stubbed axios doesn't return promise. Just pass `() => Promise.resolve({})` as a param into `jest.mock(...)` (you did it that way before, right?).

Comment: I have done that before but got error.  can't read property 'data' of undefined . It seems ```throwHttpError``` did not received the response from mocked ```axios```

Comment: @Carlos, when you tried that before, did you put `jest.mock` outside of any `describe`? I've updated the answer to make it more clear

Comment: .then  supposed to receive response object which is not there with mock function. Do we need return mock response body?

Comment: Yes, @Carlos, the answer proposes to resolve promise with empty object: `jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})),` so response object will be empty object :)